# Conflict with SVN ignore

Tags: svn

I am getting conflict with svn:ignore ... I use:

`svn propedit svn:ignore .` to locally ignore certain directories, but get a conflict when I update from another server, saying the conflict is in svn:ignore.

Is it possible to svn:ignore the svn:ignore ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a method to "svn:ignore the svn:ignore", I don't think it's possible.

The `svn:ignore` property has very likely been altered by another programmer, who has already checked that change in - so your working copy now remains in a conflicted state. You should see a file called `dir_conflicts.prej` describing the conflict in detail - which you will need to manually resolve. To quote the [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.workflow):

> You should examine the contents of this file so you can decide how to resolve the conflict. Until the conflict is resolved, you will see a C in the second column of svn status output for that object, and attempts to commit your local modifications will fail.

...and:

> To resolve property conflicts, simply ensure that the conflicting properties contain the values that they should, and then use the svn resolve --accept=working command to alert Subversion that you have manually resolved the problem.